# How to apply 3-valued-logic to SQL queries?

Tags: sql, three-valued-logic

I've been doing past paper questions and keep coming up against these questions that deal with 3 valued logic.  My notes mention it but don't give examples that relate to those asked in exams.

I understand the basis that `True = 1`, `False = 0` & `Unknown = 1/2` as well as `And = Min`, `Or = Max` and `Not(x) = 1-x`.  However I do not know how to apply it to questions such as those below:

> In SQL, discuss the possible truth values of the following expression:
>   R.a > R.b OR R.a <= 0 OR R.b >= 0
>   Justify your answer.

And:

> The phone and age fields of the Owner table might have null values in
>   them. Considering all possible combinations, show which of the three
>   truth values might be returned by the expression:
>    phone = ’141-3304913’ OR age <50 OR age >= 50

Any help in clarifying these for me would be really appreciated :)

Comment: Unknown = 1/2?? I've never seen that before. Do you have a reference?

Comment: the unknown is a half, It was in our lecture notes: Our notes say:

"• To understand how AND, OR, and NOT 
work in 3-valued logic, think of TRUE = 1, 
FALSE = 0, and UNKNOWN = ½. 
• AND = MIN; OR = MAX, NOT(x) = 1-x. 
• Example: 
TRUE AND (FALSE OR NOT
(UNKNOWN)) = MIN(1, MAX(0, (1 - 
½ ))) = 
MIN(1, MAX(0, ½ ) = MIN(1, ½ ) = ½. "

Comment: This confused me, somewhat...

Comment: Wiki says 1/2's exist: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic#Representation_of_values - news to me!

Comment: If I ever had heard of this before, I would be hard pressed to not push it directly out of my mind.  The logical conniptions used to keep UNKNOWN + UNKNOWN != TRUE seem a little odd.

Comment: I'm just going by what our lecturer has told us, and he'll be marking our exam too.

Comment: @SophiePocket: It seems that those rules actually work! Interesting... I've never seen it presented in this way before. `TRUE AND (FALSE OR NOT (UNKNOWN)) = UNKNOWN` can be thought of as `MIN(1, MAX(0, (1 - ½))) = ½`.

Comment: I assume so but I don't know how to do them or apply it. Ah yes, the theory I understand :) But when presented with questions such as the ones in my question I get confused as to how he wants it presented.  I know you won't know what format he wants, but the understanding of how to do questions like these would make me happy :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will focus on the concrete example, which is more proper for clarifying things.
Put simply, your logical expression is made of a conjunction of three clauses

```
C1: phone = '141-3304913'
C2: age < 50
C3: age >= 50
```

for which tri-boolean logic states that the result is

```
True, if any clause is true
False, if all clauses are false
Unknown, in all the other cases
```

Consequently, if the value associated with True is the largest, with False is the smallest, and with Unknown is any intermediate value, then taking the `MAX` for a conjunction proves correct. Similarly, a disjunction works with the `MIN` function. Negation works as long as we interpret any value between 0 and 1 (excluded) as Unknown; clearly, if we take 1/2 then the negation function is "stable", but that does not really matter in mathematical terms.

More operatively, the clauses clearly react to the following values (instances) of your `phone` variable `P` and your `age` variable `A`:

```
P1 such that P1 = '141-3304913'
P2 such that P2 <> '141-3304913'
P3 such that P3 = NULL
A1 such that A1 < 50
A2 such that A2 >= 50
A3 such that A3 = NULL
```

In terms of satisfaction of the clauses, we have

```
P1 -> C1 = 1
P2 -> C1 = 0
P3 -> C1 = 1/2
A1 -> C2 = 1, C3 = 0
A2 -> C2 = 0, C3 = 1
A3 -> C2 = C3 = 1/2
```

In general there exist 3*3 possible combinations, since each of your two variables takes three possible values:

```
P1 A1: C1 = 1, C2 = 1, C3 = 0 -> MAX(1,1,0) = 1 -> true
P1 A2: C1 = 1, C2 = 0, C3 = 1 -> MAX(1,0,1) = 1 -> true
P1 A3: C1 = 1, C2 = 1/2, C3 = 1/2 -> MAX(1,1/2,1/2) = 1 -> true
P2 A1: C1 = 0, C2 = 1, C3 = 0 -> MAX(0,1,0) = 1 -> true
P2 A2: C1 = 0, C2 = 0, C3 = 1 -> MAX(0,0,1) = 1 -> true
P2 A3: C1 = 0, C2 = 1/2, C3 = 1/2 -> MAX(0,1/2,1/2) = 1/2 -> unknown
P3 A1: C1 = 1/2, C2 = 1, C3 = 0 -> MAX(1/2,1,0) = 1 -> true
P3 A2: C1 = 1/2, C2 = 0, C3 = 1 -> MAX(1/2,0,1) = 1 -> true
P3 A3: C1 = 1/2, C2 = 1/2, C3 = 1/2 -> MAX(1/2,1/2,1/2) = 1/2 -> unknown
```

In particular, since C2 and C3 are mutually exclusive, you never get False as a result of the conjunction.

The expression `R.a > R.b OR R.a <= 0 OR R.b >= 0` instead presents these cases:

```
R.a <= 0, R.a > 0, R.a = unknown
R.b >= 0, R.b < 0, R.b = unknown
R.a - R.b > 0, R.a - R.b <= 0, R.a - R.b = unknown
```

Apparently we have three variables and 27 possible cases, but several related to `R.a - R.b` can be trivially ruled out.

Comment: Thanks, but how do you incorporate the OR values etc into it? No answers are given in past papers so I have no clue what the correct answer should look like.

Comment: I edited to point out the mathematics behind, I hope it suffices.

Comment: I now understand how the 2nd example (R.a <...) works :) how does your C1, C2, C3 work? I'm not sure how C1 can be 1, 0 and 1/2. Other than that I understand how you have worked out the logic :D

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: is my current answer sufficiently detailed, or do you need me to solve the R.a,R.b example too?

Comment: oh no I understand the R.a, R.b one. I just don't understand how you got to: C1 = 1; C1 = 0; C1 = 1/2
C2 = 1, C3 = 0; C2 = 0, C3 = 1; C2 = C3 = 1/2

Comment: Like what C2 and C3 stands for as it only appears in the Age clauses.

Comment: That should be clear now: the problem probably lied in the distinction between variable name and variable instance.

Comment: Thanks :D I now understand the answer :) thank you for all your help and for putting up with all my questions and struggles :)